# How do I finish a line in artist-mode without a mouse?

Tags: artist-mode

I'm using a lot of artist-mode at the moment but I find cancelling the current op very fiddly. Apparently when drawing a polyline you can use mouse-3 but this isn't very helpful when you just have keys. What's the correct way to finish the current drawing operation?

Comment: C-u RET for the final segment. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30865965/802708